# Losing My Arms Muscle

Tags: workout-routines, cardio, gym, bellyfat, meal-plan

I am 22 year old male and i am software developer.I am doing gym for months but i got little fat in my belly.So to burn that i started doing cardio in morning and gym in evening.

My schedule is like this:

7:00 - 7:45 am cardio

9:30 am - 8:30 pm Work(Including One hour of travelling)

9:00 pm -10:30 pm Gym

12:00 pm Sleep

6:30 am Wake up

After doing this for weeks i started losing my arms muscle not my belly fat.
I dont want to lose my arm muscle because its already too weak..

Here What i eat Five Times a week(Excluding Saturday and Sunday):

2 banana after Cardio and 1 cup of Oats with milk (Honey for sweetener)

At 12:00 Am i eat Omelet(2 Eggs)

At Lunch 1 cup of Rice and Dal

Before Workout I eat 2 banana and 1 glass of pomegranate juice

After Workout I eat 4 Eggs and 1 glass of Home-made Protein Shake

I had 12 inch arms which reduce to 11.5 inch now and my belly is same. I dont feel any weakness in my arms. All i feel is small biceps.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you give us some meat around your question: How do you know its muscle you are losing on your arms? How much have you lost? What does your diet look like? How many months have you been doing this? What are you doing at the gym?

Comment: Could you add what you eat and what type of training you do?

Comment: Added My Diet in question @JJosaur

Comment: What about strength? Are you becoming weaker? How do you know you have lost muscle?

Answer (score 1):

If you're experiencing a decrease in strength when you're doing arm exercises, then the decrease in size can be due to the loss of muscle. You would need to take a note of how much protein you're consuming, a lack of which could result in the muscle not being able to recover completely before the next workout. [This](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3529694/) here recommends 1.2-2g protein per kg of weight for building muscle.
Note: If you want to up the protein intake then do so gradually.

On the other hand, If you're strength levels are not declining, then the loss of excess fat from arms could be a plausible cause of the reduction in size.

In regards to your goal, there is no spot reduction, fat gets reduced all over the body contingent of course on your calories intake.[spot-reduction-myth](https://breakingmuscle.com/learn/spot-reduction-one-final-attempt-to-kill-the-myth)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Consider this article which meta-analyses the protein required, it includes reference to your study, among others: https://examine.com/nutrition/how-much-protein-do-i-need-every-day/

Answer (score 0):

If you are not weaker:

> I dont feel any weakness in my arms

Then it is extremely unlikely you lost muscle. You probably either:

- Lost fat from that area.
- Are dehydrated.

Answer (score -1):

The body does not want muscle, but fat. Muscle uses much more energy than fat. I suppose your problem is in the food. Can you show us your typical day of eating ? Maybe if you do not eat enough, your body has gone in "starvation mode"

Comment: Starvation mode for general population is a myth.